# Header element within a ListView in UWP

Tags: c#, listview, win-universal-app

I'd like to have a header element in my `ListView`, but I need the possibility to decide which item is simple and which one is header when I bind data to the ListView. This header should not be clickable and have a different color at least. In Android we do it in a custom adapter.

[image]

At the moment I get this logic of data binding to the ListView:

```
  <ListView
       x:Name="drawerListOptions"
       SelectionChanged="onSelectDrawerItem"
       SelectionMode="Single">

         <ListView.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>

                  <!--for simplicity I put only one view in as a list item -->

                     <TextBlock 
                       Text="{Binding titleItemMenu}" />

               </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
```

and C# code:

```
drawerListOptions.ItemsSource = myListOfData;
```

So I need to check in my `myListOfData` if item is simple or header. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

by using `CollectionViewSource`

although i have the same problem, i searched over web but couldn't find solution so i create this one to load data from server and show in list as group separated as `StickyHeaderListView` in android.

in XAML

```
<Page
....
 >

<RelativePanel  ... >
<Page.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" x:Name="cvs" SourceGrouped="True"/>
</Page.Resources>

    <ListView x:Name="listView"  IsItemClickEnabled="True"  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource `cvs` }}">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
            </Style>


        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>


        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <RelativePanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"  Background="White" Padding="10">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="20"></TextBlock>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True" Margin="0,0,8,0" >

                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Amount}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="{StaticResource primary}" FontSize="16"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </RelativePanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" FontSize="14" Foreground="#FF222222"  />
                    </DataTemplate>

                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>

                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewHeaderItem">

                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>

                    </Style>

                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>

            </GroupStyle>

        </ListView.GroupStyle>


    </ListView>

</RelativePanel> </Page>
```

and in source file 
bind source

```
 var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Model.YourModelHere>>(ApiResponseHere);

                    var groups = from Data in obj group Data by Data.Date;
                    this.cvs.Source = groups;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have an property in you collection item called IsSimple. In your xaml bind that variable to Header property of list view with converter. That Converter converts bool to Visibility. If value us true converter should return Visibility.Collapsed.

Answer (score 0):

In UWP, we can use `CollectionViewSource` to provides a data source that adds grouping and current-item support to collection classes.

> Use CollectionViewSource when you want to bind list controls to collections, but you want to display those collections in groups and maintain a current item independent from the list control.

For more info, see [`CollectionViewSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.data.collectionviewsource.aspx).

In my words, when you want bind to the collections and display those collections in groups without manipulating, we can use `CollectionViewSource` in this scenario.

You can use LINQ query to get results from the `ObservableCollection`. And you can set the results to the [`CollectionViewSource.Source`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.data.collectionviewsource.source.aspx).

In [`ListView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listview.aspx), we can set the [`ListView.ItemSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx) bind to [`CollectionViewSource.View`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.data.collectionviewsource.view.aspx). It can get the view object that is currently associated with this instance of `CollectionViewSource`.

For example:

Create GroupInfoList class:

```
public class GroupInfoList : List<object>
{
    public object Key { get; set; }
}
```

Create Text class:

```
public class Text : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _title;

    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set
        {
            _title = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Title");
        }
    }

    public Text(string name)
    {
        this.Title = name;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Add Header class:

```
public class Header
{
    public string HeaderTitle { get; set; }

    public Header()
    {
        HeaderTitle = string.Empty;
    }

    public static ObservableCollection<Text> GetTexts()
    {
        ObservableCollection<Text> myListOfData = new ObservableCollection<Text>();    
        myListOfData.Add(new Text("Product1"));    
        myListOfData.Add(new Text("Product2"));    
        myListOfData.Add(new Text("Product3"));
        myListOfData.Add(new Text("Setting1"));
        myListOfData.Add(new Text("Setting2"));
        myListOfData.Add(new Text("Setting3"));
        myListOfData.Add(new Text("Setting4"));
        return myListOfData;
    }

    public static ObservableCollection<GroupInfoList> GetItemsGrouped()
    {
        ObservableCollection<GroupInfoList> groups = new ObservableCollection<GroupInfoList>();

        var query = from item in GetTexts()
                    group item by item.Title[0] into g
                    orderby g.Key
                    select new { GroupName = g.Key, Items = g };

        foreach (var g in query)
        {
            GroupInfoList info = new GroupInfoList();
            if (g.GroupName.ToString() == "P")
            {
                info.Key = "Products";
            }
            else if (g.GroupName.ToString() == "S")
            {
                info.Key = "Settings";
            }
            else
            {
                info.Key = g.GroupName;
            }

            foreach (var item in g.Items)
            {
                info.Add(item);
            }
            groups.Add(info);
        }
        return groups;
    }
}
```

In XAML:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Name="MyItems"  IsSourceGrouped="True" />
    <DataTemplate x:Name="ItemListViewTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"></TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind MyItems.View}"
              SelectionMode="Single"
              ShowsScrollingPlaceholders="True"
              Grid.Row="1"
               ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemListViewTemplate}"
              Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding Key}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Set the `CollectionViewSource` source in code behind:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    MyItems.Source = Header.GetItemsGrouped();
}
```